How to withdraw this funds on sol tool

Im sorry to bother anyone , but how to withdraw this funds? The dev I hired before died a year ago and I dont know how to handle this , and how to use

Did you try the withdraw button? O.o

Yes sir, it would not proceed just a verification but nothing happens next

Hmm yeah i cant tell. Would need to find a dev to debug the code then probably.

I don't know anything bout coding
